# Fundamental theorem of calculus on a convolution, confusion

Tags: integration, convolution

I need to calculate the following, where $K(t),m(t): \mathbb{R}^+ \to \mathbb{R}$ are sufficiently smooth and integrable.
$$\dfrac{\operatorname d}{\operatorname d t} (K\ast m)(t),$$
I was thinking of the following (when the conditions are met)

$$\dfrac{\operatorname d}{\operatorname d t} \int_0^tK(t-s) m(s) \operatorname ds = \int_0^t \dfrac{\operatorname d}{\operatorname ds} K(t-s)m(s) ds= K(0)m(t) - K(t) m(0).$$

But this doesn't seem to agree with the theorem $\dfrac{\operatorname d}{\operatorname d t} (K\ast m)(t) = (K' \ast m)(t)= (K\ast m')(t).$

I guess it's because of the dependence of $t$ in the integral, since when I try:
$$\int_0^t \sin(t-s) \operatorname ds = 1-\cos(t)$$ 
while $$\dfrac{\operatorname d}{\operatorname dt} (1-\cos(t) ) = \sin(t) \not = \int_0^t\frac{\operatorname d}{\operatorname ds} \sin(t-s)\operatorname ds = \sin(0) - \sin(t) = -\sin(t)$$

What's going on here?

Comment: The "theorem" $\dfrac{\operatorname d}{\operatorname d t} (K\ast m)(t) = (K' \ast m)(t)= (K\ast m')(t)$ is for multiplication, not for convolution.

Comment: @leonbloy: It is for convolution, for multiplication you get $K' m + K m'$.

Comment: Oops, yes, I misread the second $=$ as a $+$, I'll delete the comment . thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no mystery, when sufficient conditions are satisfied, such as $a, b, f \in \mathscr{C}_{0}^{\infty}$
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \int_{a(t)}^{b(t)} f(t, s) ds
= b^\prime(t)f(t, b(t)) - a^\prime(t)f(t, a(t)) + \int_{a(t)}^{b(t)} \frac{\partial}{\partial t} (f(t, s)) ds
$$

Comment: I see what I did wrong in the example, I didn't pay any attention to the bounds. It should read 
$$\dfrac{\operatorname d}{\operatorname dt}  \int_0^t \sin(t-s)\operatorname ds = \sin(t-t)-0+\int_0^t \frac{\operatorname d}{\operatorname dt} \sin(t-s)\operatorname d s = \int_0^t\cos(t-s)\operatorname ds  = \sin(t).$$ Which checks out.

Answer (score 1):

For some mysterious reason you use a different formula for the convolution than the correct one. Remember that

$$(f * g) (t) = \int \limits _{-\infty} ^\infty f(t-s) g(s) \ \Bbb d s .$$

Assuming that all the nice conditions are met, this allows you to write

$$(f*g)' (t) = \int \limits _{-\infty} ^\infty \frac {\Bbb d} {\Bbb d t} f(t-s) g(s) \ \Bbb d s = (f' *g) (t).$$

The change of variable $u = t-s$ and integration by parts will also show that this is equal to $(f * g') (t)$, too.

Comment: I think it's convolution on the half line, like in Heaviside calculus. For functions defined in $\mathbb{R}^+$ The convolution is $\int_0^t$

Comment: @Gribouillis: You could be right, indeed; let us wait for the OP to clarify his question.

Comment: @AlexM. Yes, the functions are defined in $\mathbb{R}⁺$, I'll clarify the question.